# Kafka records and TPS

Tags: apache-kafka

As we know Kafka lets you publish and subscribe to streams of records. So how many messages equal to one records?
How we determine TPS in this case if you publish the messages to topic there?
How many messages equal to 1 TPS in real time data processing?
Is there any way to get latency on Kafka clusters/nodes?
Is there any testing tools which help to publish/receive messages to/from there?

Comment: A message is the same thing as a record... What does TPS mean?

Comment: There is mirror-Maker which provide records metrics , if you publish to broker lot's of messages it will show few records . I don't think records are same with messages . TPS means transaction per sec

Comment: The metrics says record, but for sure "record == message". Also, Kafka does not have the concept of an transaction, so I am wondering what you mean by TPS? The reported metric would be "records-per-seconds" or "bytes-per-second". Check out the docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring It's a quite open ended question and hard to answer... Also unclear what you mean by latency? There are many different latencies you could measure.

Comment: So, do someone know how many TPS (or bytes per seconds) is able to receive Kafka with an example of hardware used to get this metrics? @VinayKumar